# How can I load data from the database while backgrounded?

Tags: react-native-firebase

If I get a push notification on iOS, I want to pull some related data from the Firebase database in the background, so my user can read their articles on the train.

I'm getting the appropriate `onDisplayNotification` event, and it's reliably triggering, but when I query the database, it doesn't load the relevant data until the app is foregrounded, by which time the user may be offline.

As I understand it, this is a deliberate aspect of `react-native-firebase` to prevent the app from consuming a potentially huge amount of resources in the background of the application.

**So how can I retrieve entries from firebase.database() when my app is backgrounded?**

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is [a bug](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/1267) in version 4, which causes the OS to smack firebase down for being greedy.

Follow https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/971 for progress.